# Iterative mergesort from index a to index b

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, valgrind, mergesort

I'm trying to get some sort of mergesort going where it'll be like `mergesort(int[] a, int start, int stop)` where the start is the index to start sorting from and the stop is the index to stop sorting. The idea is that I can have 4 different threads sorting 4 subsections of the array at the same time. So I can call something like `mergesort(a, 0, length/4); mergesort(a, length/4, length/2); mergesort(a, length/2, (3/4)*length); etc.` all on different threads.

I've come across a bunch of iterative algorithms that go from `0` to `length` but when I edit those a bit to try to get them to work with subsections of the array I get segfaults on inputs that are too large and a bunch of silent errors when looking in Valgrind.

Here's what I have right now:

```
void mergesort(int *a, int *b, int low, int high) {
    int pivot;
    if (low < high) {
        pivot = (low + high)/2;
        if(level < maxlevel) { // If we have not reached the max threads to spawn
            mergesort(a, b, low, pivot); // Need to change these to spawn threads
            mergesort(a, b, pivot + 1, high);
            merge(a, b, low, pivot, high);
        } else {
            level += 2; // To tell when we can stop spawning threads
            for (int curr_size=1; curr_size<=(high-low)-1; curr_size = 2*curr_size) {
                // Pick starting point of different subarrays of current size
                for (int left_start=low; left_start<high; left_start += 2*curr_size) {
                    // Find ending point of left subarray. mid+1 is starting 
                    // point of right
                    int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;
                    int right_end = min(left_start + 2*curr_size - 1, high);
                    // Merge Subarrays arr[left_start...mid] & arr[mid+1...right_end]
                    merge(a, b, left_start, mid, right_end);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is a sorted array *if* it doesn't segfault. However with valgrind there is always one instance of this "Invalid write of size 4" error: https://puu.sh/s7zb2.png

Here's the merge function I'm using:

```
void merge(int *a, int *b, int low, int pivot, int high)
{
    cout << "merging " << low << " to " << high << endl;
    int h, i, j, k;
    h = low;
    i = low;
    j = pivot + 1;

    while ((h <= pivot) && (j <= high)) {
        if (a[h] <= a[j]) {
            b[i] = a[h]; // store element of left half in the temporary array
            h++; // shift the index of the array from which the element was copied to temporary 
        }
        else {
            b[i] = a[j];
            j++; // shift the index of the array from which the element was copied to temporary 
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (h > pivot) {
        for (k = j; k <= high; k++) {
            b[i] = a[k];
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        for (k = h; k <= pivot; k++) {
            b[i] = a[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (k = low; k <= high; k++) a[k] = b[k]; // recopy the values from temporary to original array.
}
```

What's going wrong? I have a feeling it's cause of the merge function trying to access a value it's not supposed to, but I can't seem to locate where this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: The usage of high is inconsistent. Unlike quicksort where high is the index of the last element, for mergesort high is typically the ending index (one more than the last element), so size of a sub-array = high - low. Assuming this is the way high is to be used, you need to make changes such as the while in merge() that should be using < high instead of <= high. The title is misleading, as iterative merge sort normally refers to [bottom up merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation).

Comment: This makes sense. I'll try that out. Thank you.